# Get minimum value but not zero ( 0 )

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, min

I want to get the minimum value but not zero of column from database using `Codeigniter`.

This is current code which I am using but it is giving me 0 since column also has 0 value.

```
$this->db->select_min('saleprice');
        $this->db->join('category_products', 'category_products.product_id=products.id', 'right');
        $this->db->where('category_products.category_id', $cat_id);
        $this->db->where('products.enabled',1);
        return  $this->db->get('products')->row_array();
```

Please let me know how to get minimum value but not 0

Answer (score 3):

Try to Add `where` condition like this

```
$this->db->where('saleprice >','0');
```

Then your query will become

```
$this->db->select_min('saleprice');
$this->db->join('category_products', 'category_products.product_id=products.id', 'right');
$this->db->where('category_products.category_id', $cat_id);
$this->db->where('products.enabled',1);
$this->db->where('saleprice >','0');  //Add this
```

You can also use `!=` like

```
$this->db->where('saleprice !=','0');
```